# Как перевести символ (char) в строку (std:string)—строго 1 символ

Tags: c++

```
string substr(string s, int start, int end){
    if(start < 0 || start > end || end < 0) return "";
    else if(start == end){
        return s[start];
    }
    else {
        string str;
        for(int i=start; i < end || i < s.length(); i++){
            str += s[i];
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

вот код на 4 строчки пишет ошибку, как ее исправить, нельзя возвращать 1 символ как строку из функции.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вернуть символ `char` как объект типа `string`. 
В вашем случае подойдет создание объекта через данный [конструктор](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/):

```
string (size_t n, char c);
```

То есть код возврата символа будет выглядеть так:

```
return string(1, s[start]);
```

---

Также вставить один символ можно с помощью создания нового объекта типа `string` и вызова метода `push_back`:

```
string s; 
s.push_back(s[start]);
```

Answer (score 6):

В вашем случае просто идеально просится функция-член [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
return s.substr(start,1);
```

Только учтите, что она вообще просится **ВМЕСТО** написанной вами функции!

Answer (score 1):

Проблему можно решить, убрав множественные (различные) `return` из функции. И в процессе такого рефакторинга станет ясно, что код содержит много лишнего (в том числе и ошибки). У меня получился такой итоговый вариант:

```
string substr(string s, size_t start, size_t end) {
    string str; // возвращаемая строка
    for(size_t i = start; i <= end && i < s.length(); i++) {
        str += s[i];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Что изменилось:

- типы позиций стали беззнаковыми. Поэтому не надо делать проверку <0;
- `||` заменено на `&&`, т.к. иначе при различных значениях `start` и `end` строка просто выводилась до конца (а это я считаю ошибочным поведением);
- необходимость перевода символа в строку отпала (используется уже имеющийся оператор `+=`, равносильный `push_back`);

При этом хочу заметить, что алгоритмы *STL* базируются на полуоткрытых интервалах `[begin, end)` (включает начало, но не включает конец). Ваш же код нарушает эту традицию, что не совсем хорошо при совместном использовании.

Comment: Тогда уж воспользуйтесь готовым конструктором: `string substr(string s, size_t start, size_t end) { return string(s,start,end-start /* +1 при закрытом интервале */); }` И еще - зачем копировать исходную строку? - лучше передавать ее как константную ссылку...

Comment: @Harry базовая сигнатура взята от ТС, поэтому и без const ref (всего сразу не заметишь). Даже Вы скопировали ее в таком виде :) Своим ответом я хотел указать на ошибки логики и дизайна имеющегося кода. Зная STL, исходный вопрос не родился бы вовсе у ТС, т.к. по сути является "велосипедом на костылях". Но разве кто-то может утверждать, что не делал этого сам в процессе ознакомления с языком?

Comment: Да сколько угодно :) Это не вам в упрек, а читающим в назидание (ну вот как-то рука не поднимается лезть в чужие ответы с правкой... :))